# Getting internal exception while executing pg_dump when trying to get the init migrations from hasura

Tags: hasura, hasura-docker

I want to get the latest migrations from my hasura endpoint to my local filesystem.
Command I'm trying to run

hasura init config --endpoint someendpoint.cloudfront.net/ --admin-secret mysecret

#### Output

```
INFO Metadata exported                            
INFO Creating migrations for source: default      
ERRO creating migrations failed: 
1 error occurred:
        * applying migrations on source: default: cannot fetch schema dump: pg_dump request: 500 
{
  "path": "$",
  "error": "internal exception while executing pg_dump",
  "code": "unexpected"
}


run `hasura migrate create --from-server` from your project directory to retry 
INFO directory created. execute the following commands to continue:

  cd /home/kanhaya/Documents/clineage/study-container/src/conifg
  hasura console
```

The Haura is deployed using a custom Docker image:

```
FROM hasura/graphql-engine:v2.3.0  as base

FROM ubuntu:focal-20220302


ENV HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true
ENV HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE=true
# ENV HASURA_GRAPHQL_PG_CONNECTIONS=15
ENV HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=somedatabaseURL
ENV HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET=mysecret
ENV EVENT_TRIGGER=google.com
ENV STUDY_CONFIG_ID=1


COPY ./Caddyfile ./Caddyfile

COPY ./install-packages.sh ./install-packages.sh

USER root

RUN  ./install-packages.sh


RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install -y libpq-dev


COPY --from=base /bin/graphql-engine /bin/graphql-engine


EXPOSE 8080
CMD caddy start  && graphql-engine --database-url $HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL serve --admin-secret  $HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Postgres are you currently running?
There's a conversation over here with a couple of workarounds for supporting 14 in the Hasura container (looks like version mis-match in one of the libraries):
https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/7676